# RegEx to test if a target line exists within a block of lines

Tags: regex

How would I write a Regular Expression (RegEx) that searches for a line within a block of lines?  I'm trying to test whether a line exists between a start and end block.  For instance if I'm searching for the line ^target$ after "{Beginning}" and before "{End}".

---------- Begin Example ----------

Other

lines

of text

not to

target

{Beginning}

This is

an example

of the

**target**

I'm searching

for

{End}

And yet more lines

Don't

target

these either.

---------- End Example ----------

I have found several articles about capturing everything in between the begin and end strings but nothing that would let me search for an entire line in between them.  I know that newlines (carriage returns) will probably be an issue too.

I have also found many examples of searching for a string in between a begin and end string (but not as whole lines).

Other Information: I'm performing this search in HPNA (Hewlett Packard's Network Automation) so there isn't an options to add things like "/m" at the end of the search but I can enter them inline.  For example "(?i)searchstring" to turn on case insensitivity.  The string I'm entering doesn't have slashes at all just a box to type in.

Please ask for any other reference information you might need.

Comment: Are `{Beginning}` and `{End}` whole lines? Should we match them with `(?m)^{Beginning}$`? Do you need to only match 1 line equal to `target`, or can you capture it? Also, see and try [`(?m)^{Beginning}$(?:\r?\n(?!{(?:Beginning|End)}$).*)*\r?\n\Ktarget$`](https://regex101.com/r/6HvKV2/1) (do not copy from here, copy from the regex101.com).

Comment: Yes the start and stop strings are also whole lines.  It's ok if there are multiple target lines within the block as long as there is at least one.  We're doing compliance checks on network devices so as long as the command exists within the correct block, we're good.  For example if the line "inactivity-timeout 1800" exists in the "sys sshd" block, all is well.

Comment: I should probably also mention that a block can end with nothing more than ^}$ also.  (Just in case it matters).

Comment: Ok, so does my suggestion work for you?